# How to update the mapping in Elasticsearch to change the field datatype and change the type of analyzers in string

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

While trying to update the mapping I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [timestamp] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [date]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"
mapper [timestamp] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [date]"},"status":400}
```

I m trying to run the following command on windows

```
   curl -XPUT localhost:9200/logstash-*/_mapping/log?update_all_types -d "{
    "properties":
    {
        "timestamp": 
        {
            "type": "date", 
            "format": "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "fielddata":{"loading" : "lazy"} }
        }
    }";
```

How I can change the datatype of date field from string to date type with a particular format.

I tried to change the mapping of a string datatype to change it to `eager` loading and `not_analyzed` from analyzed, but it gives the following error:

```
{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [AppName] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [AppName] has different [index] values, mapper [App
 different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [AppName] has different [analyzer]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [AppName] conflict with
existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [AppName] has different [index] values, mapper [AppName] has different [doc_values] values, cannot change from disabled to enabled, mapper [AppName]
rent [analyzer]]"},"status":400}
```

Here is my query for the same:

```
 curl -XPUT localhost:9200/logstash-*/_mapping/log?update_all_types -d "{
"properties":
    {"AppName":
        {
        "type": "string", 
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "fielddata":{"loading" : "eager"}
        }
    }
}"
```

However, if I change it from `not_analyzed` to `analyzed` it gives a `acknowledged=true` message. How can I change the analyzer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot change existing data types mapping. As Elastic docs say:

> Although you can add to an existing mapping, you can’t change existing field mappings. If a mapping already exists for a field, data from that field has probably been indexed. If you were to change the field mapping, the indexed data would be wrong and would not be properly searchable.
>
> We can update a mapping to add a new field, but we can’t change an
>   existing field from analyzed to not_analyzed.

Your only option is to create a new index with the new mapping and reindex the data from the old index to the new one.

Answer (score 9):

**No, you cannot change a single field definition**.

If you want to change the field definition for a single field in a single type, you have little option but to reindex all of the documents in your index.

---

**Why can't you change mappings?** This article [Changing Mapping with Zero Downtime](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) explains,

> In order to make
>   your data searchable, your database needs to know what type of data
>   each field contains and how it should be indexed.
>
> If you switch a
>   field type from e.g. a string to a date, all of the data for that
>   field that you already have indexed becomes useless. One way or
>   another, you need to reindex that field.
>
> This applies not just to Elasticsearch, but to any database that uses
>   indices for searching. And if it isn't using indices then it is
>   sacrificing speed for flexibility.

---

**What happens when you index a document with an incorrect field type?**

A conversion will be attempted. If no valid conversion exists, an exception is thrown.

[Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/mapping-intro.html) has a note regarding an example,  a `string` is entered but `long` is expected. A conversion will be attempted. But an exception will still be thrown if no valid conversion exists.

> [...] if the field is already
>   mapped as type long, then ES will try to convert the string
>   into a long, and throw an exception if it can’t.

---

**Can  I have the document indexed anyway, ignoring the malformed fields?**

Yes. ES5 provides a `ignore_malformed mapping` parameter. [Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) explains that,

> Trying to index the wrong datatype into a field throws an exception by
>   default, and rejects the whole document. The `ignore_malformed`
>   parameter, if set to true, allows the exception to be ignored. **The
>   malformed field is not indexed, but other fields in the document are
>   processed normally.**